# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined jQuery/PnP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I'm having a small issue with the mapping of my jQuery and can't seem to figure out what is going on.

I've tried debugging it and it's not working at all. I'm wanting to display the results of "Title" "Description" and "Link" objects inside the HTML portion of the code in a loop.

Here is the error that I am receiving:
[image]

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $pnp.setup({
        baseUrl: "https://fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training"
    });

    $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("O365RoadMap").items.get().then(function(a){
       var result = a.results.map((a)=> {return {
        Title: a.Title,
        Description: a.Description,
        Link: a.Link
        }}
    );

        /* ====== var result = a.results.map(a => ({
            Title: `${a.Title}`,
            Description: `${a.Description}`,
            Link: `${a.Link}`
            })
        ); ================================= */

        console.log(result);
        roadMapDisplay(result);
        console.debug(result);
        console.debug(roadMapDisplay);
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = roadMapDisplay;
    })

    function roadMapDisplay(result) {
        var head = result.Title;
        var desc = result.Description; 
        var link = result.Link;

        var table = $('<table/>');
            for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                table.append('<tr/>').append('<td>' + head + '</td>');
                table.append('<td>' + desc + '</td>');
                table.append('<td>' + link + '</td>').append('</tr>');
        }
        /* $('title').append(table); */
    } 
});
```

```html
<div id="title"></div>

<script src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/SiteAssets/roadmap.js?v=1"></script>
```

Comment: `a.results` is undefined. What do you see if you do `console.log(a)`?

Comment: It's says, a is not defined. I thought it would be since it's included in the function.

Comment: If the list you want to map is into "a" named object  , it's good practice to put another name into each element of results when u map them i think, otherwise the error is because is undefined a.results is null .

Comment: What would be an example Jordi? I'm still relatively new to JavaScript/jQuery so I'm trying to learn as much as possible.

Comment: Ref *"I thought it would be since it's included in the function"*. Even if it has a name, a function param will log as `undefined` if the function was called without a param or using the value of anything `undefined`. In your case, `.get()` fails and your function is called with nothing (`undefined`) as param. Check your network tab and the console to see why the call fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda function is not correctly written, please try this syntax instead:

```
var result = a.results.map((a)=> {return {//your errors where here, still you sould use lowerCased attributes
            Title: a.Title,
            Description: a.Description,
            Link: a.Link
            }}
        );
```

Comment: Hi @Luis,

I went ahead and changed the code out but it looks like the map is still being incorrect and it's giving me a map error. I do however appreciate you helping me out with this and making it a step closer.
-
$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("O365RoadMap").items.get().then(function(a) {
        var result = a.results.map((a)=> {return {//your errors where here, still you

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make some progress with the help of the community and Luis, so here is the full code that I have at the moment.

There is one small issue where it's not picking up the results var and it's showing as undefined.
[image]

Chrome console:

```
var a picks up the Title/Description/Link data and exports it into an object array  
var result = undefined  
a.results.map = cannot read property  
Title/Description/Link = undefined
```